# Ackermann Function: Prove that $A(m, n + 1) > A(m, n)$ whenever $m$ and $n$ are nonnegative integers.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction, ackermann-function

So I've been trying to solve the exercises out of **Discrete Mathematics and Its Applications** by Kenneth H. Rosen, and found myself to be stuck at this problem for quite a long time. The *Ackermann function* $A(m, n)$ is defined as 
$$\begin{cases} A(0, n) \overset{\text{def}}{=} 2n \\ A(m, 0) \overset{\text{def}}{=} 0 \\ A(m, 1) \overset{\text{def}}{=} 2 \\ A(m, n) \overset{\text{def}}{=} A(m - 1, A(m, n - 1))\end{cases}
$$Prove that $A(m, n + 1) > A(m, n)$ whenever $m$ and $n$ are non-negative integers.
Any help regarding how to approach this problem using induction would be really appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Math SE. Please update your question text to show what you have tried so far and, in particular, had any difficulty with. Thanks.

Comment: @JohnOmielan Thanks for your reply, but I am a beginner when it comes to solving induction problems with two or more variables. Basically I'm looking for a good starting point for dealing with problems such as these, and this is an example for that. I know it doesn't help you much, I wish I had more to offer, so apologies from my side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

Consider the slightly stronger statement:

> $A(m,n+1)\ge A(m,n)+2$ for all $m,n\in\mathbb N$.

Note that this also implies $A(m,n)\ge2n$ by induction over $n$.

Prove it by induction over $m$.

Base case $m=0$ follows trivially.

Inductive case: Suppose it holds for some $m=j$. We prove it holds for $m=j+1$. We prove by induction over $n$.

Base case $n=0$ follows trivially.

Base case $n=1$ follows trivially. (Show that $A(m,2)=4$ for all $m$.)

Inductive case: Suppose it holds for some $n=k\ge1$. We prove it holds for $n=k+1$::

> $A(j+1,k+2)\\=A(j,A(j+1,k+1))\\\ge2A(j+1,k+1)\\=A(j+1,k+1)+A(j+1,k+1)\\\ge A(j+1,k+1)+2(k+1)\\\ge A(j+1,k+1)+2.$

Comment: This proof is beautiful, and I get the construction in full. Thanks @SimplyBeautifulArt! Though it was a bit kind of tricky to see how the induction hypothesis on m had eventually helped in proving the induction step of n and, effectively, the induction step of m itself. May I ask how did you come up with the intuition behind the first inequality?

Comment: I just tried changing from a strict inequality to a tighter non-strict inequality.